# Drupal module for feedback based site

Tags: 7

I want to make a site using Drupal for patients to give their feedback about doctors in the country. A doctor will be classified using say Taxonomy to be in State->City->Zip code and also his/her specialization using Taxonomy.

Are there any modules I can use to quickly make a feedback site up and running ?

EDIT: I want at least the features as in http://www.ratemds.com

Comment: Can't doctors as nodes and core comments for the feedback work for your use case?

Comment: I can use forum, ratings, comments etc but module developed especially for feedback system will save my plenty of time

Comment: I think you are going to have to elaborate on what you need in terms of "feedback". As far as I am concerned, comments are feeback.

Comment: @Nigel Waters I've added the description